# Where is this map of Scandinavia (Nicolaus Germanus, 1467)

Tags: middle-ages, maps, scandinavia

Does anybody recognise this map?

[image]

Is there a better version online?

**Update**: the map was apparently printed in colour, and one version might be in Warsaw. Could also be available online, but have not been able to navigate the Polish language web site.

Comment: What is the source of your copy?

Comment: What is it supposed to be a map of?

Comment: Its a 15th century map included  in a translation of [Ptolemy's Geographia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_(Ptolemy)), updating the earlier work with more details of parts of the far northern reaches of Europe than were known to the [original author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy) in 150 CE. You can compare the region shown to a great map from 1539 by [Olaus Magnus](https://apps.lib.umn.edu/bell/map/OLAUS/lgolaus.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A version or very similar map can be found in the book ***The discoveries of the Norsemen in America : with special relation to their early cartographical representation***
by Fischer, Joseph, 1858-1944; Soulsby, Basil H. (Basil Harrington), 1864-1933 [page 168](https://archive.org/details/discoveriesofnor00fisc/page/n168/mode/1up?view=theater)

Image from above book, rotated.[image]
You can see from the caption it is a work by [Nicolaus Germanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaus_Germanus)

Germanus fits the hint offered about the map being from Florence:

> He lived first in Florence where he compiled astrological tables and
> produced his first revision of Ptolemy's Geography in 1466.

The existence of many versions are [noted as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaus_Germanus#Ptolemy%27s_Geographia):

> Nicolaus Germanus was an influential figure in the modernization and
> popularization of Ptolemy's Geographia. At least fifteen manuscript
> copies of Geographia were authored by Germanus or immediately copied
> from his work. Except for the 1482 Florence edition, all versions
> printed in the fifteenth century were based on his manuscripts.

Not sure about any better versions yet. One of the large libraries might have a better digitized copy of the original, and the caption above lists that item from Codex Vaticus Urbanus, Lat 274, f86-87, so an item from the Vatican Library...

***Located the Vatican version*** which was being referenced by Fischer in his book, you can see it [here](https://digi.vatlib.it/view/MSS_Urb.lat.274) with a nice zoomable hires viewer for close-up details. (watermarked with copyright notices, so I wont reproduce any of it here, though it does have an option for downloading a file for personal use.)

Comment: Yes that was the best copy I have seen so far. The downloaded file was low res though.

Comment: I got it at 2600 x 2090, not horrible and still zoomable in windows pic viewer...

Comment: Well, compare to when you zoom in on the web site. Big differerence.